# Matrix equation, where finding identity matrix is impossible

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equation, where I need to find what the matrix $X$ is equal to:

\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\2&3\end{bmatrix}

Let's say the first matrix is $A$, and the second one is $B$, then I need to find $AX=B$. $%(I'm sorry if I'm not writing this out properly, I don't know the all the codes I need to use. If someone could edit it I would be grateful.)$

Now normally the way I would solve this is to combine matrices $A$ and $B$ in such a way:

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2&3\\1&1&2&3\end{bmatrix}

And try to change the product matrix in such a way that I would get the identity matrix in place of $A$ and at the same time get the matrix $X$ in place of $B$. Clearly that doesn't work in my example, because I can't get the identity matrix out of $A$. So then how could I solve this problem? Any suggestions? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$A*X=B$$

correspond to the following systems

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}x_1=\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}x_2=\begin{bmatrix}3\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

with $x_1$ and $x_2$ columns of X.